# Convert excel to json in java

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to have a user upload an excel file which contains more than 50000 records from their computer then convert it to JSON.How to do this by using apache poi?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help!

[Apache-POI Getting cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents).

[How to read excel files in java using apache-poi](http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-read-excel-files-in-java-using-apache-poi)